# How can I dynamically generate selectFields

Tags: haskell, types, yesod

I'm trying to dynamically generate selectFields by mapping over `mreq selectField` using `flip`, and I'm wondering if this is the best way.

This is my attempt. After studying flip's type I'm starting to think this may be the wrong approach. Feedback welcome.

```
[(versionRes,versionView)] <- mapM (mreq (flip (selectField "Placeholder" Nothing)))
                                   versions
```

`versions`'s type is `[[(Text,Text)]]`.

I don't think the errors say anything useful as, if this is possible with this approach, it's a matter of getting the types right. I'm having difficulty doing that, and am not sure there's a solution with this approach.

For reference here are the type definitions of [`mreq`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/yesod-form/0.3.3/doc/html/Yesod-Form-Functions.html), [`flip`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3aflip) and [`selectField`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/yesod-form/0.3.3/doc/html/Yesod-Form-Fields.html).

Well, this is my next attempt.

`[(versionRes,versionView)] <- mapM (flip mreq selectField ("Placeholder" Nothing)) versions`

I'm trying to get mreq to work like this

`mreq "Placeholder" Nothing (selectField [(Text),(Text)])`

Comment: According to the linked documentation, `selectField` is a function of one argument, yet here you're providing it with two arguments (and then providing it to `flip`, which expects it to take at least two more!). I don't know enough about Yesod to suggest how to fix it, but perhaps this observation can help you get started yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come to the conclusion that flip just isn't practical, even if it might be possible.

I'm doing something like this instead.

`versionInfo <- mapM generateVersionSelectFields [[(Text),(Text)]]`

`generateVersionSelectFields version = do
   mreq (selectField version) "Placeholder" Nothing`

I leave this here so that maybe it gets improved or an alternative approach appears.